# How to segregate the roles accordingly using angular js from json file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Valid JSON

```
 [{
 "_id": "dd0af4084a0968f9301d535db",
 "user":"gdarad@gmail.com",
 "role":"Admin"
 } ,
 {
 "_id": "dd0af4084f6f4c84a0301d535db",
 "user":"hunam@gmail.com",
 "role":"editor"
 } ,
 {
 "_id": "dd0af4c84a0968f9301d535db",
 "user":"gdarad@gmail.com",
 "role":"viewer"
 } ,
 {
 "_id": "dd0af4c84a0968f9301d535db",
 "user":"hume@gmail.com",
 "role":"viewer"
 },
 {
 "_id": "dd0af4c84a0968f9301d535db",
 "user":"gdarad@gmail.com",
 "role":"editor"
 },
{
"_id": "dd0af4c84a0968f9301d535db",
"user":"hus@gmail.com",
"role":"viewer"
},
{
"_id": "dd0af4c84a0968f9301d535db",
"user":"sonn@gmail.com",
"role":"editor"
}]
```

How can i segregate the admin,role,viewer separately using angular js?

I'm using the above json file to fetch the data,i want to display the role separately in a block as in my display image attached [image: I should use ng-tags-input to input the segregated roles]

How can work with this? I have already able to use ng-tags-input to input all the roles at a single place

Comment: this question does not make much sense to me....

Comment: What have you tried? Also why not just have `"role":["viewer","admin"]`

Comment: you can just iterate list using angular.forEach and store role in some var or even can maintain it in (key,value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
    var arr = [{
      "_id": "dd0af4084a0968f9301d535db",
      "user": "gdarad@gmail.com",
      "role": "Admin"
    }, {
      "_id": "dd0af4084f6f4c84a0301d535db",
      "user": "hunam@gmail.com",
      "role": "editor"
    }, {
      "_id": "dd0af4c84a0968f9301d535db",
      "user": "gdarad@gmail.com",
      "role": "viewer"
    }];

    var emails = [];
    var users = [];
    var roles = [];
    arr.map(function(obj) {
      emails.push(obj._id);
      users.push(obj.user);
      roles.push(obj.role);
    });

    console.log(users, roles, emails);
```

[Jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ayd0ndur/)

Comment: As you have separated id's,user's and roles how can i further separate roles according to the different respective roles under usernames from the JSON as in question@Jayant Patil

Comment: you can do object.keys(jsonObject) so this will return you all key and use this keys string array